# Visual Basic hide row on DataBound

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the row to be not visible ones the users selects True but the method is not working. Please help.

Thank you!

```
 Protected Sub dg_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dg.ItemDataBound

        Dim ddl As New DropDownList
        Dim lbl As New Label
        Dim ddlretired As New DropDownList
        Dim lblretired As New Label
        If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.EditItem And dg.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex) Then

            ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddlType")
            lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lbltype")

            ddlretired = e.Item.FindControl("ddlEdit")
            lblretired = e.Item.FindControl("lblretired")

            ddl.Items.FindByText(lbl.Text).Selected = True
            ddlretired.Items.FindByText(lblretired.Text).Selected = True

            lbl.Visible = False
            lblretired.Visible = False

        End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: it is hard to tell from the sparse and sketchy description but you should be able to just use a `RowFilter` to exclude certain rows

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to suspend the binding before setting visibility to false.

From link below

> ```
> CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[MyGrid.DataSource];  
> currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
> MyGrid.Rows[5].Visible = false;
> currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
> ```

[Unable To set row visible false of a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942017/unable-to-set-row-visible-false-of-a-datagridview)