# Chart only visible rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts

I'm trying to chart only the visible rows in the datagridview. The reason is because the datagridviewer is already sorted by date and I only want those values. The other row values and coded as .Visible = false. Below is the code to show the chart and plotting the X and Y values. I've tried to work with the RowsVisible method but have come up with nothing.

```
if (CK_QA_DataDataGridView.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select Date Range and Show Results Before Chart");
}
else
{
       chart5.Visible = true;
       InitialChart.Visible = false;

       chart5.DataSource = CK_QA_DataDataGridView.DataSource;

       this.chart5.Series["X error"].XValueMember = CK_QA_DataDataGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;

       this.chart5.Series["Y error"].YValueMembers = CK_QA_DataDataGridView.Columns[13].DataPropertyName;

       chart5.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I've had the same issue with excel vba trying to plot only visible rows.  The only solution was to make a copy of the table with only the rows needed.

Comment: what is CK_QA_DataDataGridView.DataSource? a DataTable?

Comment: Yes. It's a datatable. The datatable is dt in the code, but apparently it already knows that based on the datagridview binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do that, however I doubt that you can make a `DataSource` look directly into the visibility of a DGV row.

So the best solution depends on how the visibility is determined.

If it is by evaluating some data you may succeed by using a `DataView` based on the same `DataTable` with a **`Filter`**.

But if the user can make the DGV rows invisible at will, you will have to create a separate `DataSource` for the `Chart`.

Here is a full but minimal example..

I create a table to fill the DGV first:

```
DataTable DT2 = null;

private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DT2 = new DataTable("Artists");
    DT2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    DT2.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
    DT2.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(int));

    DT2.Rows.Add("Animals", 33, 17);
    DT2.Rows.Add("Band", 45, 9);
    DT2.Rows.Add("Cream", 43, 26);
    DT2.Rows.Add("Doors", 50, 21);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT2;
}
```

Then I code a `NumericUpDown` to simulate a condition for the visibility:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int limit = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var dbo = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
        row.Visible = (int)dbo[2] >= limit;  //check for current row missing!
    }
}
```

Finally I create a `DataSource` based on the Rows in the original `DataTable` and the `Visible` property of each DGV row:

```
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DataRowView> rows2show = new List<DataRowView>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var dbo = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
        if (row.Visible) rows2show.Add(dbo);
    }
    chart5.Series[0].Points.DataBind(rows2show, "Name", "Score", "");
}
```

**Note** that you can't hide the current row. So to be safe you may need to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942017/unable-to-set-row-visible-false-of-a-datagridview) workaround..