# DataGridView C# Hide/Remove rows

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

So for one of my Windows Forms, I am using DataGridView control. I need to hide or remove some rows, because I want to show only the first 5 rows with the biggest result in the 3rd column.

I load my data from BinaryReader (DAT file). DataGridView shows my recorded data, but it loads all rows. I need only 5 rows.

```
DataGridView1.Row[].Visible = False
```

I tried with this one, but i got IndexOfOutRange exception. Any other solution ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Index starts with 0. Have you tried with correct number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable To set row visible false of a datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942017/unable-to-set-row-visible-false-of-a-datagridview)

Comment: Show the full code!! `DataGridView1.Row[]` is obviously missing the index and would not even compile..!

Comment: Have a look at this page to include code so that users can duplicate your problem and find a solotion [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the problem because your current selected cell can not be hidden. Try this:

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
DataGridView1.Row[i].Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Row in DataGrid_RowBoundEvent

then row visible false