# Monitoring Datagridview for rows that are being unhidden

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I've got a a bit of code that is allowing a Results box to pop up, populating a `DataGridView` with information. The `DataGridView` uses the same `BindingSource` that another `DataGridView` uses, so when one is clicked, the other automatically moves to the same selected cell.

The issue I am having is the `Result_DataGridView` doesn't always contain all of the same rows as the master DGV, as it hides rows that don't match a criteria. If the user clicks on a cell on the Master DGV that isn't present in the Result DGV, the Result DGV un-hides that row (as you can't hide a selected row).

I'm currently trying to use this method to hide the row that appears again, but because of how VB treats "Entering a cell" it fires before the cell actually appears (as it fires on input focus, but before the cell actually appears in the DGV, so that row never gets checked)

```
Private Sub Result_Datagridview_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Result_Datagridview.CellEnter
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim i
    For row As Integer = 0 To Result_Datagridview.RowCount - 1
        i = row
        Result = Array.Find(ResultArray, Function(x) x = Result_Datagridview.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
        If Result = 0 Then
            Result_Datagridview.Rows(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If there was a ".RowsUnhidden" event, this would work fine.

Note - the `ResultArray` contains all of the index numbers that need to remain visible, the check is performed to see if any rows exist with an index number that does not appear in the array, if so, hide it again.

Does anyone have a work around or better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

Handling the `RowEnter` event, you can [suspend the binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18942430/3773066)  and reset `row.Visible` to `False`.

So, if `ResultArray` is an `Integer` array of visible row indices, you simply do the following:

```
Private Sub Result_Datagridview_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If Not ResultArray.Contains(e.RowIndex) Then
        Dim currencyManager1 As CurrencyManager = DirectCast(BindingContext(Result_Datagridview.DataSource), CurrencyManager)
        currencyManager1.SuspendBinding()
        Result_Datagridview.Rows(e.RowIndex).Visible = False
        currencyManager1.ResumeBinding()
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: GIF demonstrating hidden rows remaining hidden]

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [`DataGridView.CellStateChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It occurs when a cell get the focus, lose it, is selected, ...