# Filtering a datagridview that does not use a DB, but loads contents from text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make my datagridview searchable, but I can't seem to get the hang of it. I've tried googling my way to the solution, whereas I found the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()) && row.Cells[0] != null)
    {
        row.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The above code is linked to a button on a form, not a lot to show there. When I enter a string into the textbox, and click the button, I get the following exception:

> Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible.

I have no idea how to deal with this exception, I've tried various changes, but nothing has helped.

Just to give you an idea, this is my form's code (I only have 1 form):

```
namespace IntegratorReader
{
    public partial class start : Form
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public start()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bOpenFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        theDialog.Title = "Open Text File";
        theDialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
        theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((theDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    string fullPath = theDialog.FileName;
                    string fileName = theDialog.SafeFileName;
                    MessageBox.Show(fullPath);
                    fillGridView(fullPath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void fillGridView (string path)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(',');

        foreach (string c in columnnames)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(c);
        }
        string newline;
        while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            newline = regex.Replace(newline, m => m.Value.Replace(',', ' '));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            string[] values = newline.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                string v = values[i];
                v = v.Replace("\"", "");
                dr[i] = v;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        file.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }

    private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()) && row.Cells[0] != null)
                {
                    row.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                   row.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Short example:

I open a .txt file with a lot of rows, whereas I take the first row and base the columns off of that. I then proceed to read the lines and put them into their columns based off of the "," splitter. I realise that this could've been done with a CSV reader of some sort, but I need this to work. This is a work related thing, so I can't give you the exact .txt file, but it generally looks like this, just with more rows and more columns:

"customerID","CustomerName"

"1","Bob"

"2","Dennis"

"3","Richard"

"4","Fernando"

You get the general idea...

Now, my question is, am I completely in the wrong about how to search in a datagridview, or is it simply a smaller issue that I'm overseeing?
Is there a better way to search in a datagridview, if yes, how?

For reference, this is how the form looks:

[image]

Comment: For the error I prefer Moory's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942017/unable-to-set-row-visible-false-of-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is very much duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942017/unable-to-set-row-visible-false-of-a-datagridview):

There two issues with your code, 1- It does not perform check for empty row(last row) and it does not suspend currencyManager while hiding a row.

To fix, replace your searchButton_Click  code with following:

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();

                if (row.IsNewRow)
                    continue;


                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()) )
                {
                    row.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                   row.Visible = false;
                }                
                currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

**Answer Update **

Another option is to set the current cell to null before deleting OR hiding a row as the error tells that "

> Row is associated with the currency Manager

".

```
if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell!=null)
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;

 row.Visible = true;//row.Visible = false
```

Comment: It'll work but Moory's solution is much simpler.