# row visibility datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm stuck with this code. I want to hide some rows so I wrote this line first and its work fine

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
      {
        if ((string)row.Cells[11].Value != (string)row.Cells[12].Value)
          {
             row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
          }
        else
          {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
          }
      }
```

I want now to hide row instead of green color so I changed

> row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;

with

> row.Visible = false;

but i get an error with that.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Can not make invisible the line associated with the map manager position.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18942430/562424

Comment: i try it but i m stuck with the same error   Could not make invisible the new line not validated

Comment: still getting error with this line row.Visible=false;   but when i try DataGridView.Rows[2].Visible = false; it works fine and hide row number2.

Comment: Problem resolved thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the row to DataGridViewBand as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.visible?view=netframework-4.8)

```
DataGridViewBand band = row;
band.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm still have the same error   --  
Can not make invisible the line associated with the map manager position. -- i don't know what's this error mean

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this method and this time row become invisible as i wanted but after that an error happen

```
                    CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                row.Visible = false;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

error :

> Could not make invisible the new line not validated