# How to hide a DataGridVew row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

In a C# WinForms project, I'm iterating through a DataGridView's DataSource as a DataTable and I'm doing a check on the source database and determining if a value in one of the columns is valid. If it *is* a valid value I want to hide it so I only end up with the DGV showing rows with invalid values.

Here's psuedo-code of what I have so far.

```
private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvMyDataGridView.DataSource);

    int intRowIndex;

    for (intRowIndex = 0; intRowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; intRowIndex++)
    {
        DataRow drValidationRow = dt.Rows[intRowIndex];

        string strNewValue = drValidationRow[5].ToString();
        // Get the current row's db record ID as a string for the db query
        int intCurrDgvRowId = int.Parse(dgvMyDataGridView[0, intRowIndex].Value.ToString());

        // Determine if we need to show or hide the DGV's row
        bool bNewValueIsValid = <db check for valid strNewValue>

        if (bNewValueIsValid)
        {
            /*
             *  Hide the DGV row corresponding to the DT row ID
             */
        }
    }
}
```

I tried what seems most logical to me:

```
dgvmyDataGridView.Rows[intRowIndex].Visible = false;
```

But when I run that I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible.'
```

I can't just do something like `drValidationRow.Visible = false`, as there's no `Visible` property on that, I'm guessing because the row is from the DataTable not the DGV.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK you can use ```SuspendBinding```, set ```Visible``` to false and use ```ResumeBinding``` aftewards. Not sure, though.

Comment: You can add a `bool` (hidden) Column to your DataTable. Set the Value of this Column to true/false when it passes/fails validation, then just use `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[MyBoolColumn] = false"`. Invert when needed, set `.RowFilter = string.Empty` to remove the filter. When a filter is active, changing the value of the bool Column will update the view immediately (no need to do anything else).

Comment: Shawn is right, have a look on : [Unable To set row visible false of a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18942430/12906488)

Comment: @Shawn, I checked out the link that JSL provided and that worked, but I ran into a situation where I ended up with no rows displaying because all values were valid, which hid all rows in the DGV. My thought was to add a counter and compare the number of rows hidden to the number of rows in the DGV and just refreshing the DGV if all rows are valid. Is there a better way to handle that situation?

Comment: @marky I don't really think I know what you're trying to achieve. If all values are valid, there will be nothing left to display. Correct?

Comment: Playing with visibility of rows is definitely wrong solution. You need to use filtering feature of data table, like explained by Jimi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need a counter. You can just refresh dgv if Rows.Count =  0 ?